# 'Newest' doesn't order questions by newest

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

[image: Newest questions]

The questions seem to be ordered by time of question and time of answer, or something else. Has it always been this way and I just noticed? I thought sorting by newest question ignored everything but the time the question was posted.

Comment: Looks like sorting is broken for some months, for both *Active* and *Newest* filters.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is not clear to me how this is a dupe.

Comment: Like I said: sort is broken, I can't see a reason to report each broken sort option as a new bug. It's the same bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The bug you linked looked to me to be about what is being displayed (dates), not the order of the sort.

Comment: Hmm.... guess you're right. Retracted.

Comment: The questions are *sorted by posting date*. However, the list shows "last modified time" instead of "posting date", making the order looks like random.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

The questions were correctly sorted by creation date but were incorrectly showing the activity date because of some broken logic.